# How to export specify html table to csv

Tags: python

I'm trying to export html tables data to csv,but I can only export all table to csv.

Here is my code,where should amend?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUcYA.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
HTMLFileToBeOpened = open(r"C:\report.html", "r",encoding="utf-16")
contents = HTMLFileToBeOpened.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll('table')
for t, table in enumerate(tables):
   df = pd.read_html(str(table),skiprows=2)

   df[0].to_csv('table%s.csv' % t)
```

Comment: I think you have to findall rows (tr) for each table 
and find all columns (td) for each row.

Then you can write it to CSV as desired.

Comment: How many tables has your HTML, can you post it?  What would you like to export exactly?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZiQM-93LGnWOLut6aqcEzeviSUudM6tP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are 19 tables,and I only want export table 4

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `bs4` library for this. You can use only `pandas` which returns you a list of dataframes and you need to choose which table you interest.

```
dfs =  pd.read_html(r"C:\report.html")
df = dfs[index_interesting_table]
```

Comment: @hc_dev Thanks, I've change

Answer (score 0):

To read in the tables from HTML (given as file `C:\report.html`) as panda *dataframes*, directly use [`read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) as suggested in [dimay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084054/5730279).

Then index the table you want zero-based. For example your 4th large table with the test-details is `dfs[3]`.

This frame can then be exported to CSV using `to_csv()` as you already did.

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs =  pd.read_html(r"C:\report.html")

# only the 4th table with test-details (tables as 0-indexed data-frames)
print(dfs[3])
dfs[3].to_csv('report_table-4_test-details.csv')
```

Will result in following CSV file written.

```
,0,1,2,3,4,5,6
0,Pass,# Failed,# Trials,Test Name,Worst Actual,Worst Margin,Pass Limits
1,,4,4,"1000 Base-T, Point A Peak Output Voltage(w/o Disturbing Signal)",510.0 mV,-106.7 %,670.0 mV < VALUE < 820.0 mV
2,,4,4,"1000 Base-T, Point B Peak Output Voltage(w/o Disturbing Signal)",510.0 mV,-106.7 %,670.0 mV < VALUE < 820.0 mV
3,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Difference A,B Peak Output Voltage(w/o Disturbing Signal)",140 m%,86.0 %,VALUE < 1.00 %
4,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point C Peak Output Voltage(w/o Disturbing Signal)",1.19 %,40.5 %,|VALUE| < 2.00 %
5,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point D Peak Output Voltage(w/o Disturbing Signal)",1.18 %,41.0 %,|VALUE| < 2.00 %
6,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point A Template Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
7,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point B Template Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
8,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point C Template Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
9,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point D Template Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
10,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point F Template Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
11,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point H Template Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
12,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point G Droop Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",96.62 %,32.2 %,VALUE > 73.10 %
13,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Point J Droop Test(w/o Disturbing Signal)",96.82 %,32.4 %,VALUE > 73.10 %
14,,0,3,"1000 Base-T, MDI Common Mode Output Voltage",26.6 mV,46.8 %,|VALUE| < 50.0 mV
15,,0,4,"1000 Base-T, Transmitter Distortion(w/o Disturbing Signal)",4.95 mV,50.5 %,VALUE <= 10.00 mV
16,,1,1,"100 Base-TX, UTP +Vout Differential Output Voltage",707.5 mV,-242.5 %,950.0 mV < VALUE < 1.0500 V
17,,1,1,"100 Base-TX, UTP -Vout Differential Output Voltage",-715.9 mV,-234.1 %,950.0 mV < |VALUE| < 1.0500 V
18,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, UTP Signal Amplitude Symmetry",-988 m,20.0 %,980 m < |VALUE| < 1.020
19,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, +Vout Overshoot",-1.9 %,138.0 %,VALUE < 5.0 %
20,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, -Vout Overshoot",-1.4 %,128.0 %,VALUE < 5.0 %
21,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, UTP AOI Template",0.000,100.0 %,No Mask Failures
22,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI +Vout Rise Time",3.872 ns,43.6 %,3.000 ns < VALUE < 5.000 ns
23,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI +Vout Fall Time",4.040 ns,48.0 %,3.000 ns < VALUE < 5.000 ns
24,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI +Vout Rise/Fall Symmetry",167.77 ps,66.4 %,VALUE < 500.00 ps
25,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI -Vout Rise Time",3.960 ns,48.0 %,3.000 ns < VALUE < 5.000 ns
26,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI -Vout Fall Time",4.151 ns,42.5 %,3.000 ns < VALUE < 5.000 ns
27,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI -Vout Rise/Fall Symmetry",191.65 ps,61.7 %,VALUE < 500.00 ps
28,,0,1,"100 Base-TX, AOI Overall Rise/Fall Symmetry",278.72 ps,44.3 %,VALUE < 500.00 ps
```

Comment: This useful for me,thanks a lot.It's much easier to use PANDAS

Comment: @余振暘 ZhenYang, 你好 在SO 表决  [What should I do if someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)